# Derivatives of Implicit Functions (Abstract Case)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-differentiation, function-and-relation-composition

I have never been good at differentiation of implicit functions in cases when in a function is given, much less in abstract cases with composite functions. Hopefully someone can help me get started on the process to answering this homework question:

Suppose $y = f(x)$ is a solution of $G(x,y) = 0$, where $\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} \neq 0$, and let $g(x)=F(x, f(x))$. Show that $g'(x) = \frac{(F_1 G_2 - F_2 G_1)}{G_2}$, the right side being evaluated with $y = f(x)$.

My tutor and I have attacked this from every angle and can't figure it out. Please help!

Comment: apply chain rule to $G(x, f(x))=0$ to obtain $f'(x)$. then, apply chain rule of $F(x, f(x))$ and plug in $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G(x,f(x))=0$

$$dG=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial G}{\partial f}\frac{d f}{d x}dx=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d f}{d x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial G}{\partial f}}$$
and
$$dg=dF(x,f(x))=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}\frac{d f}{d x}dx$$
$$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}\frac{d f}{d x}$$
by replacing $\frac{d f}{d x}$
$$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}\frac{\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial G}{\partial f}}$$
$$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial G}{\partial f}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial G}{\partial f}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to make sure that I understand, you used the chain rule to differentiate $G(x,f(x))=0$, and then you solved for $\frac{df}{dx}$ algebraically by subtracting $\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}} dx$ and divided out the rest. Then, also using the chain rule, you took the derivative of $g$ which is equal to $F$ and substituted in our value for $\frac{df}{dx}$. Sweet, thanks again!

Comment: @Josh exactly as you described